# Use linux style path when calling python on Windows with bash

Tags: python, windows, bash, path

I'm using git bash to run a python script that calls some Linux tools (scp, ssh) on Windows.

My python script takes a path as a parameter. However, when calling os.path.join to do some operation on that path, the returned value is a windows-formatted path (back slashes). Passing that path to the scp or ssh tools fails or does not behave properly.

Is there any easy way to 'force' Linux path style in python 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
import os
import sys

>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> p = Path(os.path.dirname(sys.executable))
>>> p
WindowsPath('C:/Python36')
>>> x = p.joinpath('Scripts/pip3.6.exe')
>>> y = p.joinpath('Scripts\\pip3.6.exe')
>>> print(x.as_posix())
C:/Python36/Scripts/pip3.6.exe
>>> print(y.as_posix())
C:/Python36/Scripts/pip3.6.exe
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks.